# javascript oop access extending 'class' member from base

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am using prototypal inheritance in JavaScript and have hit an issue I can't quite figure out. Many JS inheritance examples show accessing a super's members from a sub, but I need to access the sub's members from the super.

I'm building a tool to performance test mapping web services. I want to support multiple versions of the WMS protocol. I want to keep all shared functionality / properties in a WMS base class wherever possible, and only provide specific version implementation details where necessary. My WMS v1.1.1 function looks like this:

```
function wms111() {
    this.version = '1.1.1';
}
wms111.prototype = new wms();
```

My wms function (short version) is as follows:

```
function wms() {

    var that = this;

    this.HTTPMethod = 'GET';

    this.descriptionParameters = {
        service: 'wms',
        version: that.version,
        request: 'getcapabilities'
    };
}
```

I then test this with a call like

```
var service = new wms111();
var descriptionParameters = service.descriptionParameters;
```

I get the `descriptionParameters` object with the `service` and `request` properties correctly defined, but `version` is undefined.

Can anyone help me figure out how I access the correct properties from wms111?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it work as intended:

```
function wms111() {    
    this.descriptionParameters.version = '1.1.1';
}
```

Instead of defining a brand new property, just overwrite the property that should be different in the child.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Wd9vE/1/

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot. Can you explain what's going on when it doesn't work? I thought that the new wms111() object would be treated as a single entity that just unions everything in both wms() and wms111() functions, so using `that` (this) wouldn't differentiate between them

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong on this one, but I'm pretty sure you can't. Inheritance works top-down, not bottom-up. You can overload the function in the subclass, but that's essentially treating that function in the superclass as an abstract function, which has to be overloaded.

Comment: that possibility did occur to me, but then with JavaScript I've come to expect to be able to do stuff that doesn't make sense :)